# Resolve instances without injection in asp net core

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection

How can I resolve instances without injection in asp net core

When we used spring .NET we could get an instance by something like:

```
StaticFactory.GetInstance<T>();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ASP.NET Core, services are available within a request from `HttpContext`:

```
HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(MyService));
```

Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2#request-services

> Prefer requesting dependencies as constructor parameters to accessing the `RequestServices` collection.

Comment: Thanks! (7 more chars)